# Qt application blinking at startup because of drawing text in a custom paint event

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I discovered a very strange behavior which causes blinking (white rectangle is shown as the main window for about half a second) at application start up in some cases. After a long time of test and trial I narrowed down the problem to the situation when a text is first drawn in paint event of my custom widget. If a text is drawn also in another widget such as `QLabel`, the problem is gone. But my application main window only has tool buttons with icons and a custom widget which draws text, no other widgets. The white blinking is very ugly and I would like to get rid of it, ideally with some proper solution and without nasty hacks of introducing some artificial text drawing widgets. Moreover I am not very comfortable because I really do not know what is actually going on. Why the custom widget causes blinking and `QLabel` not? To prove the behavior try the following code (the same problem is in C++/Qt so it is not caused by Python wrapper). Then try to uncomment the marked line and comment the next one to see that the blinking is gone.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QLabel

class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.drawText(20, 20, "XYZ")

app = QApplication([])
container = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(container)
# label = QLabel("ABC")  # uncomment this to prevent blinking
label = QLabel()  # comment this out to prevent blinking
layout.addWidget(label)
layout.addWidget(CustomWidget())
container.resize(600, 600)
container.show()
app.exec()
```

Any ideas what is going on there? I am using Qt 5.9.2.

Comment: I do not observe that problem, maybe it is a bug, it could indicate which is your OS and graphic card and driver version.

Comment: I have fully updated Windows 10, some on-chip Intel card in Dell Latitude notebook. I guess this is not the problem.

Comment: Have you observed the same behavior on another computer?

Comment: Can't try that at the moment.

Comment: I mention it because I've seen several posts of that type, and in the end were bugs of the driver version.

Comment: I think QLabel draws text like I am drawing it it does not call different routines or does it? It seems like the font glyphs are somehow initialized before the first use and with `QLabel`, they are initialized before the screen is shown (i.e. no blinking) while in my custom widget they are initialized just in the middle of the paint event which is happening when the windows is already shown (i.e. blinking). Maybe something with double buffering. Or maybe something else...

Comment: As I mentioned I do not have that problem, paintEvent is a function that is called only when it is required to repaint, for example when you change the size of the widget or forces it through update(), (I think Qt should implement double buffering in a private part of the framework).

Comment: I have just tested this on a very different machine (also Windows 10) and it gives the same result. I.e. when the first text is drawn in a custom `paintEvent()`, the main window blinks when is first displayed, it shows a white rectangle instead of the main window for about 0.3 seconds.

Comment: If I did not tell you, now I say: I recommend you report it as a bug showing proofs like image and giving technical information of the computers that used PyQt5

Comment: I created a bug ticket https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66416